# How do I download a file inside a Windows EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2008-r2

I RDP'd into an instance, but when I attempt to download file, an error message appears: "Your current settings do not allow this file to be downloaded."

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact URL of the file you are trying to download, you can use PowerShell as a workaround:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/path/to/file", "path/to/destination/file.zip")
```